# Sending mail from php script in a scheduled task using sendmail

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I am sending mail using sendmail package in my application
the mail sending function is simple :

`mail($to,$subject,$mailmessage);`

My application is installed on Windows Server 2008. I have scheduled a task using task scheduler to run the script every 5 minutes

All the script runs but mail is not working the error I get on the cmd display is :

> PHP Warning:  mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, ve
> rify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp
> www\RCold\mailingcron.php on line 3
> PHP Stack trace:
> PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\RCold\mailingcron.php:0
> PHP   2. mail() C:\wamp\www\RCold\mailingcron.php:3

> Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify
> your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp\www\R
> Cold\mailingcron.php on line 3

> Call Stack:
> 0.0008     227816   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\RCold\mailingcron.php:0
> 0.0008     228800   2. mail() C:\wamp\www\RCold\mailingcron.php:3

If I run the same script on a browser, the mail function works properly.

How can I run the mail function from command line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PHP CLI** and **mod_php/Apache** use different php.ini files in WAMP.  Make sure your settings are the same in both, or use the `ini_set()` function as indicated in your error message.

Here are some common locations for each:

`C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.X\php.ini` CLI

`C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.X\bin\php.ini` APACHE